# Designing Java Object for SQL Query

Tags: java, sql

Are there any good utils/frameworks which could generate Java Object for SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know its gonna be enough helpful but, as you asked for utils, I would suggest you to read about the [QUERY OBJECT PATTERN (P of EAA, M. Fowler)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html), if you have time to implement something, its a good beginning, otherwise you may lookfor  any ORM framework.

Comment: Are you aware of any frameworks, which could help in designing subQueries and joins too?
For ex: Select * from person where id = (select * from map where id=223)

Answer (score 2):

[QueryDsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) automatically creates Query Objects from your Hibernate, JPA or JDO classes, but also [from your DB schema](http://source.mysema.com/static/querydsl/2.1.1/reference/html/ch02s04.html#d0e654).

> Querying with Querydsl SQL is as
>   simple as this :

```
QCustomer customer = new QCustomer("c");

SQLTemplates dialect = new HSQLDBTemplates(); // SQL-dialect
SQLQuery query = new SQLQueryImpl(connection, dialect); 
List<String> lastNames = query.from(customer)
    .where(customer.firstName.eq("Bob"))
    .list(customer.lastName);
```

It also [supports subqueries](http://source.mysema.com/static/querydsl/2.1.1/reference/html/ch02s04.html#d0e812):

> To create a subquery you create a
>   SQLSubQuery instance, define the query
>   parameters via from, where etc and use
>   unique or list to create a subquery,
>   which is just a type-safe Querydsl
>   expression for the query. unique is
>   used for a unique (single) result and
>   list for a list result.

```
query.from(customer).where(
  customer.status.eq(
      new SQLSubQuery().from(customer2).unique(customer2.status.max()))
  .list(customer.all())
```

> Another example

```
query.from(customer).where(  
  customer.status.in(new SQLSubQuery().from(status).where(
    status.level.lt(3)).list(status.id))  
  .list(customer.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using torque to do that. There is an example(Tutorial) which show what it can do at  http://db.apache.org/torque/releases/torque-3.3/tutorial/step5.html

But what exactly is it you want? Do you just a simple way to serialize/unserialize objects to the database, and load them based on a primary/foreign key, or do you need to issue really complicated queries?